# Analyzing outliers in 3 uncorrelated variables

Tags: r, correlation, outliers

I am trying to search for outliers in my data. I've plotted some Boxplots but there seems to be no outlier (which would be understandable since my dataset is small). Do you know if it makes any sense to do a multivariate analysis (bagplot) even if my variables are completely uncorrelated with each other?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @ncnc_2020, your question seems to be if it makes sense to do this analysis which I think is rather a general statistic question that an R question. Or do you have trouble with *how* to do it?

Comment: You certainly can have a multivariate outlier that is not a marginal outlier. Consider 1000 points uniformly distributed between 0 and 1, perfectly correlated with another set of 1000 points. Those points are on a straight line from (0,0) to (1,1). Now consider a point at (0.7, 0.3). Each component is perfectly plausible according to the marginal distributions, but that point is certainly not in the mainstream of the rest of the data! Be careful about discarding outliers, however. We tend to discourage that on Cross Validated.